# ttempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, findviewbyid

I created a Fragment and I want to load a WebView. But i get this error:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
```

The Code:

```
    public class StudentPlanFragment extends Fragment {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View onCreateView = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        mWebView = (WebView) onCreateView.findViewById(R.id.webViewStudentPlan);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://example");
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


        return onCreateView;
    }
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Looks like your `onCreateView`-object is null.

Comment: post your xml here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit as below:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT_NAME, null);
mWebView = (WebView) rootView .findViewById(R.id.webViewStudentPlan);
mWebView.loadUrl("http://example");
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


return rootView ;
}
```

Comment: Correct, the compiler can't read your mind and know which layout file you want to use for your Fragment out of nothing

Answer (score 1):

You must inflate your xml in the code to find the `WebView` from the xml layout.

```
public class StudentPlanFragment extends Fragment {

private WebView mWebView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //Delete the below commented code, it is just to highlight the mistake in the existing code

    /* View onCreateView = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);*/

    View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_XML_LAYOUT_FILE_NAME, container, false);

    mWebView = (WebView) onCreateView.findViewById(R.id.webViewStudentPlan);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://example");
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


    return onCreateView;
    }
}
```

Comment: It will surely give an compilation error. as onCreateView is not initailized. :)